# How to have smaller font sizes for smaller devices?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing an app and using hardcoded font sizes.  In the iOS simulator it looks as expected on an iPhone 14 and above but when I tried it on an iPhone SE, it's too large.

How can I handle different font sizes based on the device?

When thinking about it, all I could really think of is using a `GeometryReader` to check the display height/width and then conditionally select a font size but that seems a little messy. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Don't hardcode font sizes. Use `Font.TextStyle` so you get an appropriate size automatically based on the device and the user's device settings.

Comment: See [Human Interface Guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/typography/#dynamic-type-sizes) about Typography and dynamic type sizes. Adapt dynamic type in your app to obey the user's custom settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extraordinarily bad practice. If I, as a low vision user, turn up my font size to something I can read, please don’t fight me.

Depending on your location and market sector, you might even be violating accessibility laws.

Redo your design to adapt to dynamic text and varying device sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **'@Environment'** property wrapper to access the device's size category, which is based on the user's font size settings. Use this property to adjust your font sizes dynamically.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .font(.system(size: getSize()))
}

func getSize() -> CGFloat {
    switch sizeCategory {
    case .extraSmall, .small:
        return 12
    case .medium:
        return 16
    case .large:
        return 20
    case .extraLarge, .extraExtraLarge, .extraExtraExtraLarge:
        return 24
    default:
        return 16
    }
  }
}
```